# Почему не инициируется задача конвертации видео через Celery в django-videokit?

Tags: python, django, redis, rabbitmq, celery

Решил применить для небольшого проекта Python/Django батарейку **django-videokit**  (см: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-videokit/0.0.4 и https://github.com/pstreck/django-videokit). И в общем, оно почти заработало. Но непонятно почему не происходит создание (конвертация) исходного видео в другие форматы. Django-videokit должен через Celery запустить утилиту *ffmpeg* и «приготовить» видео-файлы необходимых форматов (*.mp4*, *.ogg* и *.webm*). Cсылки на эти файлы окажутся в соответствующих полях **VideoSpecField**.

В `models.py` все почти как в документаци:

```
from videokit.models import VideoField, VideoSpecField
from my_project import settings

class tbVideoItems(models.Model):
    szVideoName = VideoField(
        upload_to = settings.PATH_FOR_VIDEO,
        null = True,
        blank = True,
        width_field = 'iVideoWidth',
        height_field = 'iVideoHeight',
        rotation_field = 'fVideoRotation',
        mimetype_field = 'szVideoMimetype',
        duration_field = 'iVideoDuration',
        thumbnail_field = 'imgVideoThumbnail'
    )
   iVideoWidth = models.IntegerField(null = True, blank = True)
   iVideoHeight = models.IntegerField(null = True, blank = True)
   fVideoRotation = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = True)
   szVideoMimetype = models.CharField(max_length = 32, null = True, blank = True)
   iVideoDuration = models.IntegerField(null = True, blank = True)
   imgVideoThumbnail = models.ImageField(null = True, blank = True)

   szVideoName_ogg = VideoSpecField(source = 'szVideoName', format = 'ogg')
   szVideoName_webm = VideoSpecField(source = 'szVideoName', format = 'webm')

   class Meta:
       verbose_name = u"Видео-ролик"
       verbose_name_plural = u"Видео-ролики"
       ordering = ['szVideoName']`
```

Исходное видео «засасывается» и полям *iVideoWidth*, *iVideoHeight*, *fVideoRotation*, *szVideoMimetype* и *iVideoDuration* присваиваются правильные значения. Создаётся превьюшка *imgVideoThumbnail*. Поля же **VideoSpecField** (*szVideoName_mp4*, *szVideoName_ogg* и *szVideoName_webm*) остаются пустыми. Надо запустить генерацию. Для этого в `views.py` (например) пишем. что-то типа:

```
# ...
qVideos = tbVideoItems.objects.all()
    for i in qVideos:
        if i.szVideoName_ogg == "":
            i.szVideoName_ogg.generate()
        else:
            print i.szVideoName_ogg
        # ...
# ...
```

Соответсвенно генерация запускается. *szVideoName_ogg* получило значение, но что странно, при просмотре значения постоянно меняются. Например:

> videos/Futurama-S7e01\fc54f1c9ace5c6403763ae772a59adc6.ogg

при следующем вызове:

> videos/Futurama-S7e01\c57acb82ed465ed362f190495d9c4990.ogg

при следующем:

> videos/Futurama-S7e01\ed046299f6622802ca36f76961b8aebf.ogg

и так далее...

Но, что удивительно, при просмотре через админку, значение меняется каждый вызов. При просмотре же через `views.py` переенная *szVideoName_ogg* не меняется(!). В целевой папке никаких **.ogg** файлов нет. Для контроля проверил: вообще на диске (включая временные папки) нигде нет ни одного **.ogg**.

Что еще примечательно: при запуске под *nix видео-файлы, «всасанные» через **szVideoName**, не имеют статуса на чтение и, соотвественно, не могут быть отданы клиенту веб-сервером: 

`$ ls -l
-rw------- 1 web web   69537154 фев 27 17:05 Futurama-S7E07.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 web web      13053 фев 27 17:05 Futurama-S7E07.mp4.thumb.jpg`

При этом у создаваемой превьюшки (**.thumb.jpg**) с правами все в порядке. Под Widows таких проблем нет и видео-файл через веб остдаётся.

В самом django-videokit в task.py есть описание создания процесса для конвертации и создания файла:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(
    ['ffmpeg', '-i', source_file, '-y'] + options + [temp_file])
```

Но вот создается это процесс, и если создается, то работает ли он?

В django-videoki упоминается, что как-то можно проверить статус создания альтернативных видео-файлов, но не сказано как :(.

Все усложяется тем, что это мой первый опыт использования Celery и как там должна происходить инициализация очередей, выполнение заданий и тому подобное -- не понимаю. Ни RabbitMQ, ни Cellery никак не настраивал (из коробки). Куда «копать» не понимаю.

Пренес videokit из виртуального окружения внутрь проекта. В `celery.py` написал:

```
app = Celery(
    'my_project',
    broker='amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//',
    backend='amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//',
    include=['videokit.tasks']
)
```

При вызове `celery worker` (при включенноем виртуальном окружении) получаю:

> ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'videokit.tasks.generate_video'.
>    The message has been ignored and discarded.

Где регистрировать задачи videokit?

P.S. В инструкциях по установке django-videokit указано, что предварительно надо установить RabbitMQ. Но в `requirements.txt` примера указан в числе прочего еще и redis==2.10.5. В коде `celery.py` примера тоже иcпользуют Redis... У меня установлено и RabbitMQ, и Redis... Но как они взаимодейтсвуют и как происходит управление -- не понятно.